# Why can I not write MessageBox.Show("asdfasdf{0}", i);?

Tags: c#, windows

```
int i = 85; 
Console.WriteLine("My intelligence quotient is {0}", i);  // Kosher
MessageBox.Show("My intelligence quotient is {0}", i); // Not Kosher
```

I find this most distressful an debilitating. One works and not the other? What is the source of this behavioural incongruity? The more I think about it the less I can imagine, and failure to understand too often turns to self-loathing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Console.Writeline` has these overloads:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.writeline.aspx

In particular, [an overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/828t9b9h.aspx) that accepts a format string and a [params array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Here's another method that is quite similar:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx

I don't know why [MessageBox.Show](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox.show.aspx) doesn't have the overload.  I'd guess it is because there are already so many other overloads for that method.

But you can get a similar effect by adding `string.Format` to it:

```
public void ShowMessageBox(string format, params object[] args)
{
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format(format, args));
}

// ...

ShowMessageBox("You entered: {0}", someValue);
```

Answer (score 9):

The `Show()` method simply has no proper overload.

It was added to `Console.WriteLine` as matter of convenience, but it's not integral part of every .NET method.

To achieve same effect, use `string.Format` manually:

```
MessageBox.Show(string.Format("asdfasdf{0}", i)); // Kosher
```

Answer (score 1):

Why is hard to tell (it is just how MS defined it) but IF you want to write "congruent" code for both cases then you can use [`string.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) - for example like this:

```
MessageBox.Show (string.Format ("asdfasdf{0}", i));
```

or

```
Console.WriteLine (string.Format ("asdfasdf{0}", i)); // although this is unneccesary!
```

Answer (score 0):

`WriteLine()` method has overload [WriteLine(string format, Object arg0)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/586y06yf.aspx) and `MessageBox.Show()` hasn't such overload. Instead you need to use:

```
MessageBox.Show(string.Format("asdfasdf{0}", i));
```

Answer (score 0):

`Console.WriteLine`, `Debug.Print` and so on are methods that are intend to accept a string to write it to a certain place. `MessageBox.Show` is a method that will show a messagebox modal to the user. There are a lot more options to set (like title, buttons, etc.), so it would not make sense to accept formatting logic at this point.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Or if it is so important for you ,you can create you're own class like that and use for that purpose you already asked :

```
 class myMessageBox
    {
        private myMessageBox()
        { }

        public static void Show(string text,params object[] i)
        {
            text = String.Format(text, i);
            MessageBox.Show(text);
        }
    }
```